# Error response from daemon: No such image: ubuntu (tag: latest) right after after pulling from docker hub

Tags: ubuntu, docker, dockerhub, ubuntu-15.04

I had pulled the image `ubuntu` from the docker hub after a search using - 
`sudo docker search ubuntu` and pulled the image using `sudo docker pull ubuntu`. The command - `sudo docker images` were listing around 5 images related to ubuntu with different tags. The curious part is, I was not able to run the image - `ubuntu` with any of the tags available even with the default - `latest` tag..! The run command `sudo docker run -it ubuntu bin/bash` tries to pull the image again and finally ends up with the message: `error response from daemon: No such image: ubuntu (tag: latest)`

My Ubuntu version: `15.04` 
and my docker version details:

```
Client version: 1.5.0
Client API version: 1.17
Go version (client): go1.3.3
Git commit (client): a8a31ef
OS/Arch (client): linux/amd64
Server version: 1.5.0
Server API version: 1.17
Go version (server): go1.3.3
Git commit (server): a8a31ef
```

Please take a look at the image attached for more info.[image]

Comment: could you try with an up-to-date version of Docker? (1.8.2 by now)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the docker architecture, a docker image consists of various layers though for a user, it just combines and shows as a single image.
While pulling/pushing to and from the docker hub, we can observe this layered concept as docker lists a number of files(in fact, various layers of the corresponding image) during push/pull operation.

For me, after pulling the image, docker somehow failed to update its image lists as a single un-tagged file and thus couldn't recognize images which I mentioned(**ubuntu:latest**).

A **system restart** updated the docker image list(combined the various layers to a single image) and thus solved the issue.

Comment: @McLan would you please give more details like: 
 1) Docker version
 2) Platform you are currently into etc.